# Select input from getmdl-select with Vue 2.0

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-design-lite, vue.js

I was trying out [getmdl-select](https://github.com/CreativeIT/getmdl-select) with [Vue2.0](https://vuejs.org/guide/). in the view, I got it correct and working as expected, but it is not changing the model associated. Here is the code:

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select getmdl-select__fullwidth">
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" id="age" name="age" v-model="age" type="text" readonly tabIndex="-1" data-val="1"/>
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="age">Age</label>
    <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu" for="age">
      <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="1">1 Month Old</li>
      <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="11">11 Month Old</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have put `v-model="age"` with input field as given above, but age variable is not updating when selecting values from dropdown.

However vanilla `select` input works fine:

```
<select v-model="age">
  <option value="" disabled hidden>Select Age</option>
  <option value="1">1 Month Old</option>
  <option value="11">11 Month Old</option>
</select>
```

I tried to created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzgpjhao/1/) of this, however in fiddle, UI is not coming properly, in local at-least UI works properly.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in the Console ?

Comment: I think somethint is not right with the library you are binding to the fiddle, because it does not even get updated without vue

Comment: @Belmin I don't get any error in console, in UI it selects the value, but the model remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `v-model.lazy`

```
<input type="text" v-model.lazy="age"/>
```

[docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#lazy)

Comment: This simple thing solved my 2 hours of frustration. Thanks a lot.